# SQLAlchemy Session not returning connection to pool

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy in a PyQt GUI application. We create a new session for each top level window, and call `Session.close()` when the window is closed.

Unfortunately, it seems that when a user performs many actions in quick succession, we're seeing `QueuePool` overflow errors. In spite of the session being "closed" the connection doesn't seem to return to the pool until the GC has had a chance to clean up reference cycles. The primary culprit of these cycles seems to be between `references()` and their backref.